# Win 10, batch file / exe not working as expected from task scheduler

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Long story short, I have an .exe I wrote many years ago that I no longer have the code for. I want to run this exe as a screensaver.

However, it expects a key press of the ENTER key to start it. I have written batch files using nircmd to send the key, I have tried writing a separate application which is referenced by the batch file to send the key.

Whatever method I use works perfectly from the desktop, but when I try to run it from task scheduler "on idle" the key does not make it through. I have even compiled the batch file into an exe.

The original program is around 10,000 lines long so rewriting it is not an option at this point. I am just trying to understand why it will run from explorer and not task scheduler.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried everything in that article, I don't understand the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by editing the registry to point the the .exe I complied from the .bat to be my screen saver. I still don't understand why it wont run from task scheduler... but at least it works.